# How do I send a command when x and y are center during face tracking?

Tags: python

Please forgive my awful code, this is just a hobby for me. But I am trying to have python play a sound when both x and y axis of face tracking are at a determined center point. Right now I'm testing with playing a sound, once the sound plays I can swap playing a sound with sending data to arduino to spool up a brushless motor for the orbeez minigun. The rest of the code is working, but I cannot get the sound to play. The sound WILL play if I call it a different way.

Here is a snippet of the code

Also, I have tried many different ways of 'if (xcenter + ycenter) == 2:', this is just the last one tried.

```
# This will send data to the arduino according to the x coordinate
def angle_servox(angle):

    if angle>320:
        prov=1
        ser.write(b'2')
        print("Right")
        xcenter = 0

    elif angle<250:
        prov=2
        ser.write(b'1')
        print("Left")
        xcenter = 0

    elif angle>250 & angle<320:
        ser.write(b'0')
        print("Stop")
        xcenter = 1

# This will send data to the arduino according to the x coordinate
def angle_servoy(angle):

    if angle>250:
        prov=3
        ser.write(b'4')
        print("Down")
        ycenter = 0

    elif angle<75:
        prov=4
        ser.write(b'3')
        print("Up")
        ycenter = 0

    elif angle>80 & angle<240:
        ser.write(b'5')
        print("Stop")
        ycenter = 1

# import the haarcascade file
face_casc = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

#train the face for recognition
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read("recognizers/face-trainer.yml.txt")

labels = {"person_name": 1}
with open("pickles/face-labels.pickle", 'rb') as f:
    og_labels = pickle.load(f)
    labels = {v:k for k,v in og_labels.items()}

# for default camera put value 0 or else 1
videoWeb = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
n=0


while (videoWeb.isOpened()):
    print(ser.read().decode().strip('\r\n'))
    ret,imag = videoWeb.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(imag, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #cv2.imshow('xyz',imag)
    faces = face_casc.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.4,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30,30)
        )
    if (xcenter + ycenter) == 2:
        voice.play(active2)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are not correctly interrogating the information you get back from the cv2 face detection (also, you could probably delete the two `angle_servo()` functions for this question).

At a high level, you want your script to:

1. Setup your camera stream
2. Continously get images from the camera and find faces
3. If there is a face in the "middle" play your sound

I've never used openCV, but based on some example code I found [here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html), a revision of your script might be:

```
# Setup our face detection
face_casc = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read("recognizers/face-trainer.yml.txt")

# Setup our video input
videoWeb = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def is_close_to(self, other_pt, error=5):
        x_is_close = abs(self.x - other_pt.x) <= error
        y_is_close = abs(self.y - other_pt.y) <= error

        return x_is_close and y_is_close

# If an image from the video camera looks like this:
#
#     x-->
#    +-------------+
#  y |  A          |    A is at (10, 20)
#  | |             |
#  v |             |
#    |          B  |    B is at (300, 500)
#    +-------------+
#
# Our predetermined references points
A = Point(10, 20)
B = Point(300, 500)

# Continuously get images from the camera
while (videoWeb.isOpened()):
    # and try to find faces in them
    ret,imag = videoWeb.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(imag, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_casc.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.4,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30,30)
        )

    # I'm just guessing here, I have no idea if "size" is a property or not
    middle_of_imag = Point(imag.size.x/2, imag.size.y/2)

    # check the location of every face we found
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        face_pt = Point(x, y)

        #NB: it might be better to get the "middle" of the face
        #face_pt = Point(x + w/2, y + h/2)

        if face_pt.is_close_to(A):
            print("face at point A")
        if face_pt.is_close_to(B):
            print("face at point B")
        if face_pt.is_close_to(middle_of_imag):
            print("face somewhat in the middle")

        # if x in faces is between 250 & 320 AND y in faces is between 80 & 240: send 'fire'"
        if (250 <= x <= 320) and (80 <= y <= 240):
            print("send fire")
```

Comment: While this does work, it needs to work in a range. Instead of servo_x being set at 123, it would need to be all numbers <123 and <250, as an example.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is space for solving your whole problem here, and besides, that would deprive you of the great feeling you'll get once you solve it ;-)

Comment: Yeah I've spent I don't even know how many hours searching and trying different things to solve this one. I'm just going to scrap this python project and go a different direction.

Comment: Hmm, have you had any luck without worrying about the servo position? E.g. have 2 different sounds that play if there is a face in either of two locations? I'll make an edit to show what I mean

Comment: Servo position really doesn't matter. The 'def angle_servo(angle)' is just reading the position of the face on the screen and sending a command (b'5') to arduino. The comment 'Left/Right/Up/Down' is just printed for calibration purposes. The main part of the code that matters in this instance is

    elif angle>250 & angle<320:
        ser.write(b'0')
        print("Stop")

and

    elif angle>80 & angle<240:
        ser.write(b'5')
        print("Stop")

Comment: That essentially tells the servos to stop, meaning the face is in a center point of the screen where small movements from the target won't bring the target out of range. So what I am trying to do is say, when the face is in this area of the screen, send a fire command . And if it moves out of this range to do nothing/stop firing.

Comment: After looking at the help you've given, another way I can think of saying it is something that says "if x in faces is between 250 & 320 AND y in faces is between 80 & 240: send 'fire'" but I have no idea how I would put something like that in python.

Comment: Hot diggity daffodils, that got it SOLVED. I had something similar to that, but overcomplicated and it sent 'fire' regardless of face position. Thanks for the help, I don't really have anyone I can bounce ideas off of like this and appreciate everything. Time to finish this thing up and make it rain orbeez.

Comment: Ha, I got that feeling. I'm glad I could help :-)